# ScrollHeader in ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, uwp

In UWP we can use of [ScrollHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.scrollheader?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) in ListView or GridView. I need like this ScrollHeader control in WPF Applications. What is the best way?

[in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/scrollheader):

```
<Page xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls" .../>

<ListView Name="listView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind _items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.Header>
        <controls:ScrollHeader Mode="Sticky">
            <TextBlock Text="Scroll Header" />
        </controls:ScrollHeader>
    </ListView.Header>
</ListView>

<!-- or -->

<GridView Name="gridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind _items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <GridView.Header>
        <controls:ScrollHeader Mode="Sticky">
            <TextBlock Text="Scroll Header" />
        </controls:ScrollHeader>
    </GridView.Header>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried and implemented the same this way.

```
 <ListView Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="50">
                        <TextBlock Text="This is a test text to go more than 50 width" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```